# ui-router $transitions hooks not getting called on browser reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm making an app in Angular 1.5.8 with ui-router 1.0.3.
Ui router's hooks are great but **they are not working on browser reload**.

Here is my **config block** for registering states:

```
(function(app) {
    'use strict';
    app.config(configFn);

    configFn.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function configFn($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                component: 'loginComponent'
            })
            .state('selfcare', {
                url: '/',
                component: 'selfCareComponent',
                abstract: true
            })
            .state('selfcare.dashboard', {
                url: 'dashboard',
                component: 'dashboardComponent'
            })
            .state('selfcare.appHome', {
                url: 'appHome/:id',
                component: 'appHomeComponent'
            })
            .state('selfcare.serviceHome', {
                url: 'serviceHome/:id',
                component: 'serviceHomeComponent'
            })
    }

})(angular.module('selfcare'));
```

And following is the **run block** for registering hooks on transitions:

```
(function(app) {
    'use strict';
    app.run(runFn);

    runFn.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$transitions' ,'$localStorage'];

    function runFn($rootScope, $transitions,  $localStorage) {

        $transitions.onStart({to:'**'}, function(transtion){
            $rootScope.ngProgress.start();
        })

        $transitions.onSuccess({to:'**'}, function(transtion){
            $rootScope.ngProgress.complete();
        })

       $transitions.onBefore({to:'login'}, function(transtion){
            if($localStorage.isLoggedIn > Date.now()){
                return transtion.router.stateService.target('selfcare.dashboard');
            }
        })

       $transitions.onBefore({to:'selfcare.**'}, function(transtion){
            if(!$localStorage.isLoggedIn || $localStorage.isLoggedIn < Date.now()){
                $localStorage.$reset();
                return transtion.router.stateService.target('login');
            }
        })
    }

})(angular.module('selfcare'));
```

I'm not able to figure out where am I doing wrong. Hooks are called once the app is stable and work correctly but on browser reload I can open any url and none of the hooks are called.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You pasted two config blocks. Please paste the run block.

Comment: @georgeawg sorry my bad, pasted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow managed to do what was required but I don't know if that is the best way. I wanted to write the transitions in the run block.

Transition object which is argument of hook callback provides an `injector` which can be used to get runtime services in `config` block of app.

(We can also inject `$injector` in `config` block)

```
(function(app) {
    'use strict';
    app.config(configFn);

    configFn.$inject = ['$transitionsProvider'];

    function configFn($transitionsProvider) {

        $transitionsProvider.onStart({ to: '**' }, function(transtion) {
            transtion.injector().get('$rootScope').ngProgress.start();
        })

        $transitionsProvider.onSuccess({ to: '**' }, function(transtion) {
            transtion.injector().get('$rootScope').ngProgress.complete();
        })

        $transitionsProvider.onBefore({ to: 'login' }, function(transtion) {
            var $localStorage = transtion.injector().get('$localStorage');
            if ($localStorage.isLoggedIn > Date.now()) {
                return transtion.router.stateService.target('selfcare.dashboard');
            }
        })

        $transitionsProvider.onBefore({ to: 'selfcare.**' }, function(transtion) {
            var $localStorage = transtion.injector().get('$localStorage');
            if (!$localStorage.isLoggedIn || $localStorage.isLoggedIn < Date.now()) {
                $localStorage.$reset();
                return transtion.router.stateService.target('login');
            }
        })
    }

})(angular.module('selfcare'));
```